# ng-animate not working as intended

Tags: angularjs, css

I am attempting to animate the process of inserting a new list-item into a list.

Following the instructions at http://www.nganimate.org/

Step 1: I establish a base class

```
.animate-enter {
  -webkit-transition: 400ms cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.250, 0.750, 0.750) all;
    transition:  400ms cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.250, 0.750, 0.750) all;
      opacity: 0;   
}
```

Step 2: Establish a class for final state

```
.animate-enter.animate-enter-active {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

However, this doesn't seem to be animating anything.

Plnkr here:

http://plnkr.co/edit/lpMdhRpQjf5QlNtfb5dn?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that ng-animate is built into 1.1.5, but not the version you're using, which is 1.3. You'll have to download or reference ngAnimate as a seperate module if you're using it with this version using a script tag such as `//code.angularjs.org/X.Y.Z/angular-animate.js`. [See Here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate)

But [here's](http://plnkr.co/edit/sJSunmUR9jcNLM1Dp9Np?p=preview) a plunker with your code using angular 1.1.5, and i added a search filter to better show the animation. I believe you were also missing a bracket after you defined your animate class.

Also you had opacity in `transtition` without the prefix in your css before the function as well as `all` after the function. but that just seemed like a typo:

```
.animate-enter {
  -webkit-transition: 400ms cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.250, 0.750, 0.750) opacity ;
  -moz-transition: 400ms cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.250, 0.750, 0.750) opacity ;
  -ms-transition 400ms cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.250, 0.750, 0.750) opacity ;
  -o-transition: 400ms cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.250, 0.750, 0.750) opacity ;
  transition: 400ms cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.250, 0.750, 0.750) opacity ;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from including the angular-animate.js script into your page, you need to inject the reference to the ngAnimate as follows:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngAnimate']);
```